# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied after uploading to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

I had a website that is running perfectly fine,

However when I decided to move it to Azure (Uploaded by FTP), I get the error

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

The connection to my database hosted in my own server's SQLServer could not be opened.

Is there any additional steps to be made after uploading the entire website?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you imported your Model locally, you need to update your connectionString from your Web.config file. Set your server, catalog, user id, and password appropriately